# how to represent estimated variance in LaTeX

Tags: statistics

How would I represent the estimated variance symbol in LaTeX: 
i.e, `\Var(\tau)` for Var(τ) . But how to write with an inverted V symbol above the Var, basically the symbol for estimated variance

Comment: Do you mean `\hat` or `\widehat`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{\widehat{Var}}

\begin{document}
\[
\Var(\tau)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Campa answers your question exactly.  The code below shows two alternatives (both of which I prefer).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}


\begin{document}
\[
 \hat V, \quad \hat{\mathbb{V}} 
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]