# Vector Arrow Weirdness

Tags: math-operators, vector

Here's something strange:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Vi}{\vec{i}}
\begin{document}
$\Vi$
$\vec{i}$
\end{document}
```

When I compile this, only the second one produces the desired result. The other gives me a tilde over the i! What gives?

Comment: Why should you define `\Vi` with `\DeclareMathOperator`? If your aim is to have an upright “i”, then `\newcommand{\Vi}{\vec{\mathrm{i}}}` is what you need.

Comment: I'm not sure... is there a better option? I just want something quicker to type than $\vec{i}$ as I write up exams, etc... Perhaps I'm missing the thrust of your question.

Comment: @Shay egreg is asking "Why did you choose to use `\DeclareMathOperator`?" What is your desired outcome?

Comment: `\DeclareMathOperator` is for very particular objects such as `\log`, `\max` or `\sin`. You just need `\newcommand{\Vi}{\vec{i}}`, probably, or better, `\newcommand{\Vi}{\vec{\imath}}`

Comment: Ok, that's great. I'm still curious about why \DeclareMathOperator turns $\vec$ into $\tilde$. That seems rather odd behavior to me.

Comment: @egreg I guess `\operator@font` is interfering with the math accent. Did I just got lucky with http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/261966/82917?

Comment: Thanks, @campa. I guess the general worry is this: I've always used DeclarMathOperator for things like this. If that's not what I should be doing, fine, but this is the first time it's ever broken for me and I'd like to know in general when it's going to break.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\DeclareMathOperator` function is for defining a quite narrow kind of objects; for instance `\log`, `\exp`, `\sin` or `\max` use (an equivalent form of) it. So it's for defining function symbols that should consist of letters in the same shape as normal text, as opposed to math italic.

Basically `\DeclareMathOperator{\foo}{blurb}` does something like

```
\newcommand{\foo}{\mathop{\mathrm{blurb}}
```

(I just omit irrelevant technical complications). The `\mathop` bit is what produces the peculiar spacing around operator names; for instance there is a space in `$\log x$`, but not in $\log(xy)$`. Of course,`\mathrm` is what selects upright letters.

The input

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$\mathrm{\vec{i}}$
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

but as soon as we uncomment the loading of `amsmath` we get

[image]

The tilde instead of an arrow is a “feature”<sup>1</sup> in `amsmath`, then.

What you need is

```
\newcommand{\Vi}{\vec{i}}
```

or, maybe better,

```
\newcommand{\Vi}{\vec{\imath}}
```

where the “i” loses its dot.

[image]

---

<sup>1</sup> It's not the only “feature” of `amsmath` related to math accents. The word “feature” is used in its common meaning of “bug”.

Comment: What is a way around for `\DeclareMathOperator{\grad}{\vec{\nabla}}`?

Comment: @SubhajitPaul What's wrong with it?

Comment: I meant in what other way can I have the `\vec{\nabla}` symbol with proper operator spacing? The above way produces a `tilde` over the `nabla`.

Comment: @SubhajitPaul I'd go with `\newcommand{\grad}{\mathop{\vec{\nabla}}\nolimits}` or `\DeclareMathOperator{\grad}{\mathnormal{\vec{\nabla}}}`